# SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host xx.xx.xx.xx: connection closed by remote host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, capistrano3

We are implementing capistrano for our rails application (Rails 5 + aws + ruby 2.3.1 + capistrano 3).

#### deploy.rb

```
server 'my aws server ip', port: 3000, roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:myusername/myrepo.git'
set :application, 'myapp'
set :user, 'ubuntu'
set :puma_threads, [4, 16]
set :puma_workers, 0
set :pty, true
set :use_sudo, false
set :stage, :production
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind, "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#        {fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys:     %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true # Change to false when not using     ActiveRecord
namespace :puma do
desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
task :make_dirs do
on roles(:app) do
execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
end
end
` before :start, :make_dirs` `end` `namespace :deploy do` ` desc "Make         sure local git is in sync with remote."` ` task :check_revision do` ` on     roles(:app) do` ` unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse     origin/master
puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
puts "Rungit pushto sync changes."
exit
end
end
end
desc 'Initial Deploy'
task :initial do
on roles(:app) do
before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
invoke 'deploy'
end
end
desc 'Restart application'
task :restart do
on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
invoke 'puma:restart'
end
end
before :starting, :check_revision
after :finishing, :compile_assets
after :finishing, :cleanup
after :finishing, :restart
end
```

#### deploy/production.rb

```
set :user, "ubuntu"
server "my aws ip", port: 3000, roles: [:app, :web, :db], :primary => true
set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys:     %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa) }
```

#### Gemfile

```
gem 'capistrano', require: false
gem 'capistrano-rvm', require: false
gem 'capistrano-rails', require: false
gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
gem 'capistrano3-puma', require: false
```

While I execute the following command,

```
cap production deploy
```

I get the following error:

```
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host xx.xx.xx.xx: connection closed by remote host
```

Please help me get out of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `ssh` port is `22`, are you sure about `3000` ?

```
server "my aws ip", port: 3000
                    ^^^^^^^^^^
```